# How to understand continuity equation intuitively as Lorenz covariant?

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, continuum-mechanics

As we know, it is natural that we derive the differential form of continuity equation

$${\frac {\partial \rho }{\partial t}}+\nabla \cdot \mathbf {j} =0$$

from the integral form, in the view of absolute space and time.

And we will find that the equation is Lorenz covariant: Once we define 4-vector $j\equiv(\rho, \vec j)$, we will see $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$ gives the continuity equation.

So, we find that, the continuity equation is a general  incompressible flow equation $(\nabla\cdot \vec u=0)$ in Minkowski space.

How is a compressible flow also an incompressible flow in Minkowski space? I cannot understand this intuitively.

**P.S.** I think the surprising part is that the equation derived in the view of absolute space and time naturally meets Lorenz covariance, which implies continuity equation might be more fundamental than we thought. Are there any other examples?

Comment: When assuming that the equation is covariant one is also assuming that $(\rho, \vec{J})$ transforms as a four vector. That is a very strong **physical** hypothesis which may be false. Everything relies upon this non-trivial implicit assumption

Answer (score 1):

The continuity equation is very fundamental. It is a kind of "nothing gets lost theorem".

Let us define the total charge $ Q(t) = \int_V d^3x \rho(t,x)$.
Using the continuity equation you can prove that the total charge is conserved - you get the integral representation.

$\frac{d}{dt} Q(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_V d^3x \rho(t,x) = \int_V d^3x \left(\partial_t \rho(t,x) \right) = -\int_V d^3x \left(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec {j}(t,x) \right) = -\int_{\partial V} d\vec{S}\cdot \vec j (t,x) =0$

We used the Stokes theorem and the boundary conditions in the next to last and last step respectively.

EDIT: Wihtedeka points out a good interpretation of the continuity equation. If the total charge changes inside the volume V then it has to be through some flux across the boundary of that volume.

Continuity equation applies to all kinds of "compressible fluids", e.g.: real fluids, charge densities, mass densities (in space dust).

Comment: As an interpretation of the integrals one might add that if the total charge changes inside the volume V then it has to be through some flux across the boundary of that volume.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have some thoughts on my question after thinking for a while. Still waiting for other illuminating discussions.

We cannot simply consider continuity equation as a general incompressible flow equation in Minkowski space. Because for incompressible flow, we know the density of each [fluid parcel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_parcel) is constant; While we cannot define a counterpart concept of density, or say, volume, in Minkowski space. Because while the volume is limited and localized, the existence for $q$ is eternal, which means its distribution in time is unlimited, from infinite past to infinite future.

So it is wrong to understand the continuity equation as a general incompressible flow equation in Minkowski space.